# Facebook app stay login on canvas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-javascript-sdk, omniauth

i have a facebook app that can be access through facebook canvas or directly via the url.

so everytime my user revisit my app, they have to click on sign in again, even if within the same session(For fb canvas only, session works fine for direct)

Is there any tutorial or scripts that i can add to my webpage using javascript to check if user is a register user, and if yes, auto sign them in?

I'm using rails3 and omniauth facebook gem. Thanks.

Comment: If the user already connected to your app before, then they _will_ be automatically logged in on the canvas page; and you will find the necessary info (user id, auth token) in the signed_request parameter (server-side), or you can just use `FB.getLoginStatus` out of the JS SDK to check if the user is connected to your app.

Comment: thanks man, :D. i couldnt find any documentations before this